# Issue while showing button on above keyboard when enable in swift

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard

i'm trying to show a button above keyboard when it is enable but it isn't working fine, when keyboard get open button doesn't move above keyboard and when i hide keyboard it move at the top of screen, How i can show button just above keyboard when it is shown to user. This is my code for showing button,

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpVC.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
             NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(SignUpVC.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.nextBtn.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.nextBtn.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height   //can adjust as keyboardSize.height-(any number 30 or 40)
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.nextBtn.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.nextBtn.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Button frame has an initial y value that isn't 0 , so you need to perserve it and set back

**Option 1** : save button frame and restore it

```
var btnFrame:CGRect!
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        btnFrame =  self.nextBtn.frame 
        self.nextBtn.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height   //can adjust as keyboardSize.height-(any number 30 or 40) 
    }
} 
@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) { 
    self.nextBtn.frame  = btnFrame
}
```

**Option 2** :  move the view itself

```
@objc func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height   //can adjust as keyboardSize.height-(any number 30 or 40)
        }
    }
}

@objc func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0 {
        self.view.frame.origin.y = 0
    }
}
```

> Replace `UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey` with `UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey`

Comment: I have multiple fields on same screen when i click another textfield it moves button more above. how can i make button remain at same place when user open another textfield. @Sh_Khan

Answer (score 0):

as a matter of fact you should change the frame of your view instead of changing button's frame. Place your button below the view and when keyboard pops up change push view upward.